# Shadow PackageParser.call ParsePackage PackageParser$Packageparserexception

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I am trying to move my code to dynamic feature and while moving the test cases i created a test package inside dynamic feature module and moved related test classes there. 
The test cases are not running and failing with below exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to parse /Users/anujjha/../build/intermediates/apk_for_local_test/debugUnitTest/packageDebugUnitTestForUnitTest/apk-for-local-test.ap_
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPackageParser.callParsePackage(ShadowPackageParser.java:69)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.loadAppPackage_measured(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:314)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.lambda$loadAppPackage$1(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:284)
    at org.robolectric.util.PerfStatsCollector.measure(PerfStatsCollector.java:53)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.loadAppPackage(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:282)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.installAndCreateApplication(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:178)
    at org.robolectric.android.internal.AndroidTestEnvironment.setUpApplicationState(AndroidTestEnvironment.java:169)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.beforeTest(RobolectricTestRunner.java:301)
```

There are all junit test cases. Any idea how to make it work.and what can i check in code or gradle.

Comment: The first line seems to refer to a file which does exist but I am not sure why its only _ap and not .apk

Comment: I'm facing the same issue since we moved to dynamic feature. Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Your test package doesn't get included in dynamic feature module. We ended up having a module with common test files and then include them in dynamic feature's test.

Comment: @AnujKumarJha Do you have an example of how you resolved this? I have the same problem. My common test util classes are in their own module and included in the dynamic feature tests. But I still have this problem.

Comment: You have to check how you are building your bundles and using it. you having issue with debug build or release build? or both?

Comment: debug builds.. As that's what I am testing.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Hey its been long time. As mentioned earlier we created common module and moved changes to that instead of using dynamic module.

Comment: @TheGraduateGuy By Common module you mean you have created a separate library module, added your dynamic feature module as dependency in it and wrote all tests in that module. I am facing the same issue and could not find out any possible solution. Pls provide some screenshot or description about how you resolved it .